# Compare results of multiple VLOOKUP formulars and return value that is not #N/A

Tags: excel, vlookup

In A1:N1 are several VLOOKUP results from different tables. Only one result in row 1 is not "#N/A" but a text string, say "text1" or "text2" etc.

In O1 it should return the one string in row 1 that is not "#N/A". Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: Will it always be only 1 result which is not the error value?

Answer (score 2):

If there will always be only one result which is not the `#N/A` error value, you can use a simple `Index` lookup with the `Match` function as the column parameter:

```
 =INDEX($A$1:$N$1,1,MATCH("*",$A$1:$N$1,FALSE))
```

This searches for the wildcard `*` which will return the column position of the first cell which contains (non-Error) text value.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use a straight 'Lookup' function on the range:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:N1<>"#N/A"),A1:N1)
```